# How to add a border to the selected Menu Item in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, css

In my .aspx file there is 5 MenuItems and 5 views respectively. What I want I am explaining below:
 On page load view1 will be enabled and there will be a border-bottom on MenuItem1.
If I click MenuItem2 then View2 will be displayed and there will be a border-bottom on MenuItem2. Same things will happen to other menuitems and views also.

Here is my .aspx file:

```
<div class="courseoptions">

            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticMenuItemStyle-HorizontalPadding="30px"  runat="server" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick" CssClass="menucolor" ForeColor="Black">
                <StaticSelectedStyle ForeColor="#15904D" BorderStyle="Outset" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="#11A15D" />
               <Items>
                   <asp:MenuItem Text="OVERVIEW" Value="0" Selected="true" ></asp:MenuItem>
                   <asp:MenuItem Text="SYLLABUS" Value="1"></asp:MenuItem>
                   <asp:MenuItem Text="CERTIFICATE" Value="2"></asp:MenuItem>
                   <asp:MenuItem Text="DISCUSSION" Value="3"></asp:MenuItem>
                   <asp:MenuItem Text="NOTES" Value="4"></asp:MenuItem>
               </Items>
                <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="30px" />
            </asp:Menu>

</div>
<div class="coursedetails">
            <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex ="0">
                    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                        <div class="view1">
                            <p>
                            Welcome to the Complete front end developer Bootcamp. This is one of the most comprehensive bootcamp available online. so, if you are new to web development, thats great news because starting from the scratch is always easy. 
                            </p>
                            <p> This course gives you a unique experience and focus only on front end web development. First we will get professional and free web development tools, then we will start with HTML. Once we cover this ground, we will take down our very first challenge. Further we will learn HTML5 and start our first project. <br /> Moving further we will take CSS and CSS3. After that we will learn Bootstrap and optimize our sites for mobile view. After that we will learn JavaScript and jQuery and will do some projects in that.</p>
                            <p> Structure of this is designed after research and you will never feel bore in this course. After completion of the course, you will be able to design a web page in the exact same design that is on your mind or you might have seen on some theme website.</p>
                            <p> Creating a web template of your own or edit one, you will be a full skill ninja to do the job.</p>
                        </div>

                    </asp:View>
                    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                        <h2>
                            Here is the syllabus
                        </h2>
                    </asp:View>
                    <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
                        <p>Certificate</p>
                    </asp:View>
                    <asp:View ID="View4" runat="server">
                        <p>discussion</p>
                    </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="View5" runat="server">
                    <p>Notes</p>
                </asp:View>
                </asp:MultiView>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With css you can get the `anchor` (text), but getting the `li` that wraps it will be difficult (or impossible?).

```
li[role="menuitem"] a.selected { border-bottom: 2px solid blue; }
```

If you can use jquery, this will work:

```
$("a.selected").closest("li").css("border-bottom", "2px solid blue");
```